# Couldn't layout Subviews in UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, autolayout

I'm trying to make a custom header for 0 section of my UITableView. Here's the code I'm using to create this header:

```
class ProfileHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    // MARK: - Subviews
    
    private var statusText: String = ""
    
    private lazy var userImage: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: me.login))
                
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 48
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    ...
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupUI()
        addSuviews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
     // MARK: - Private

    private func setupUI() {
        backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }
    
    private func addSuviews() {
        addSubview(userImage)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        let layoutMarginGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
            
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            userImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            userImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            userImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
            userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
        ])
    }
}
```

Here's how I add this header in my ViewController:

```
    private func setupConstraints() {
        feedView.frame = view.bounds
        
        feedView.delegate = self
        feedView.dataSource = self
        feedView.register(PostViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        feedView.register(ProfileHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "ProfileHeaderView")
        //feedView.register(ProfileHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "profileView")
    }
```

Here's the result I'm getting:
[image: Screenshot]

As you see, image is ignoring safeArea on the screen. How to fix it?

Comment: It does not appear you are adding the sub views to the contentView

Comment: @DavidH OK, I replaced:
`addSubview(userImage)`
with:
`contentView.addSubview(userImage)`
But the profile picture is still where it was on the screenshot

Comment: @Philipp - are you trying to use this as a **section header** (`viewForHeaderInSection`)? Or as the **table view header** (`tableVIew.tableHeaderView`)?

Comment: @DonMag actually I need to make it a header for section 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you left out much of the needed code (such as your cell class and your controller class).

And, you haven't shown your code for `viewForHeaderInSection`.

But, we can look at a quick example...

**your `ProfileHeaderView` with minor modifications**

```
class ProfileHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    
    // MARK: - Subviews
    
    private var statusText: String = ""
    
    private lazy var userImage: UIImageView = {
        //let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: me.login))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "face"))

        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 48
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return imageView
    }()
    
    //...
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupUI()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupUI()
    }
    // MARK: - Private
    
    private func setupUI() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        addSuviews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    private func addSuviews() {
        contentView.addSubview(userImage)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // this will avoid auto-layout complaints
        let bottomC = userImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0)
        bottomC.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            userImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            userImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            
            //userImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            bottomC,
            
            userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
            userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
        ])
    }
}
```

**a simple single-label cell class**

```
class PostViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let theLabel = UILabel()
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

**a simple view controller class with table view** - number of rows set to 30 so we can see the section header stays in place...

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    let feedView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.title = "Log In"
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        feedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(feedView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            feedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            feedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            feedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            feedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        feedView.delegate = self
        feedView.dataSource = self
        feedView.register(PostViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        feedView.register(ProfileHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "ProfileHeaderView")
        
        // remove default padding
        feedView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0

    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! PostViewCell
        cell.theLabel.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if section == 0 {
            let v = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "ProfileHeaderView")
            return v
        }
        // return some other header view for subsequent sections?
        return nil
    }
}
```

Looks like this when run:

[image]

Comment: this is absolutely what I needed! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide` instead of `contentView.layoutMarginsGuide` as your layout guide.

`safeAreaLayoutGuide` represents the layout area in between bars (e.g the layout between the status bar and the home bar)

**EDIT:** It probably makes more sense to correctly set the constraints of your table view (using the `safeAreaLayoutGuide`) instead of having to do that for individual views within your table view